# Evaluate : $\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_0^\infty {1\over1+kx^{10}}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, improper-integrals

Evaluate : $\displaystyle\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_0^\infty {1\over1+kx^{10}} \, dx$.

From reading other answer to similar questions, I realized that I may have to use dominated convergence theorem to interchange the limit and integral. It would be nice if someone could just explain how to use that theorem in this context to solve this or if that guess is wrong, just tell the right approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the dominated convergence theorem in this case.

Do a substitution $u=x\cdot k^{1/10}$ to see
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{1+kx^{10}} = k^{-1/10} \int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{1+x^{10}}.$$

So the limit evaluates to $0$.

Comment: I can see that ${1\over k^{1/10}} \to 0$. So, I only need to prove further that the integral is some finite value ?

Comment: The integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{1+x^{10}}$ is finite: at $0$ there is no problem and at $\infty$ we have decay of order $10$ (where we would only need $x^{-p}$ for some $p>1$ for convergence).

Comment: Sorry but I'm not able to get the idea behind "decay of order 10 ..." . Can you please elaborate on that a bit ?

Comment: Ok, you believe that $\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{1+x^{10}}$ is finite right? The other part $\int_1^\infty \frac{dx}{1+x^{10}}$ we can estimate as follows: for $x\ge 1$ we have $1+x^{10}\ge 1+x^2$ and as we know $\frac{d}{dx}\arctan(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$, so $\int_1^\infty \frac{dx}{1+x^{10}}\le \int_1^\infty \frac{dx}{1+x^2}=\arctan(\infty)-\arctan(1)=\pi/2-\pi/4=\pi/4<\infty.$